# bulk rename pdf files with name from specific line of its content in linux

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, rename, batch-rename

I have multiple `pdf` files which I want to rename. new name should be taken from pdf's file content on specific(lets say 5th) line. for example, if file's 5th line has content `some string` <-- this string should be name of file. and same thing goes to the rest of files. each file should be renamed with content's 5th line. I tried this in terminal

```
for pdf in *.pdf
do
   filename=`basename -s .pdf "${pdf}"`
   newname=`awk 'NR==5' "${filename}.pdf"`
   mv "${pdf}" "${newname}"
done
```

it copies the files, but name is invalid string. I know the system doesn't see the file as plain text and images, there are metadata, xml tags and so on.. but is there way to take content from that line?

Comment: Have you opened the file(s) in a text editor?

Comment: yes, I know that they have special symbols and some other data, and they not look the same as in pdf

Comment: Which means "line 5" has no meaning you can depend on unless you already know the specific file format. If you know what you are looking for - i.e., you know specific key strings that can be located before and behind the filename - then you can use those sentinel values instead of just reading for line 5. Otherwise, I don't think this is going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, `bash` and its usual utilities are not able to read pdf files. However, `less` is able to recover the text from a pdf file. You could change your script as follow :

```
for pdf in *.pdf
do
    mv "$pdf" "$(less $pdf | sed '5q;d').pdf"
done
```

Explanation :

- `less "$pdf"` : display the text part of the pdf file. Will take spacing into account

  - make some tests to see if `less` returns the desired output
- `sed '5q;d'` : extracts the 5th line of the input file

Optionally, you could use the following script to remove blank lines and exceeding spaces :

```
mv "$pdf" "$(less "$pdf" | sed -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/ \+/ /g' | sed '5q;d').pdf"
```

Comment: thanks for reply. sorry I'm noob at bash scripting, for now it renames file with empty string, I will try to figure out

Comment: that's because the 5th line of your pdf is actually blank. try to do `less myfile.pdf` and see if the text you want is really the 5th line

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove all blank lines from your file. I'll edit my answer to address this.

Comment: yes, thanks, you were right. but now it copies names with spaces, it there way to trim string directly in script? I tried your bottom code, but it cannot open the file

Comment: My new edit should do the trick. The first 2 sed commands remove blank lines and exceeding spaces